# Video is still being encoded message in Rails app using redis and sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am new to rails. I am doing exactly (copy paste) per

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-12-08-building-video-sharing-app-server-messaging-ruby/

On top of this I am running

```
 redis -server
```

and

`bundle exec sidekiq`

but I get message `"Video is still being encoded."` 
I checked in database and my videos are getting inserted. Here's the log for Redis and sidekiq

Redis--
    $ redis-server

```
[64544] 11 Oct 07:36:14.426 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
[64544] 11 Oct 07:36:14.427 # Unable to set the max number of files limit to 10032 (Operation not permitted), setting the max clients configuration to 8160.
[64544] 11 Oct 07:36:14.427 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

below is sidekiq log

```
2016-10-12T04:21:00.251Z 73605 TID-l83gw INFO: [Sidetiq] Enqueue: VideoPublisher (at: 1476246120.0) (last: 1476246060.0)
2016-10-12T04:21:16.178Z 73605 TID-oxkz28srs VideoPublisher JID-19a982e30a3c181f8f757b50 INFO: start
2016-10-12T04:21:16.180Z 73605 TID-oxkz28srs VideoPublisher JID-19a982e30a3c181f8f757b50 INFO: done: 0.002 sec
2016-10-12T04:22:00.271Z 73605 TID-ou3i0 INFO: [Sidetiq] Enqueue: VideoPublisher (at: 1476246180.0) (last: 1476246120.0)
2016-10-12T04:22:16.146Z 73605 TID-v65wg VideoPublisher JID-e0c8138c9c3bdbcef3711c76 INFO: start
2016-10-12T04:22:16.149Z 73605 TID-v65wg VideoPublisher JID-e0c8138c9c3bdbcef3711c76 INFO: done: 0.003 sec
2016-10-12T04:22:31.984Z 73605 TID-y7u04 ThumbnailCutter JID-da2c68736611327a846e7df6 INFO: start
sidekiq 4.2.2 VideoShrimp [0 of 25 busy]: No such file or directory - ffmpeg
2016-10-12T04:22:31.991Z 73605 TID-y7u04 ThumbnailCutter JID-da2c68736611327a846e7df6 INFO: fail: 0.007 sec
2016-10-12T04:22:31.991Z 73605 TID-y7u04 WARN: {"class":"ThumbnailCutter","args":[7],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"da2c68736611327a846e7df6","created_at":1476245384.080985,"enqueued_at":1476246151.9836948,"error_message":"exception class/object expected","error_class":"TypeError","failed_at":1476245384.2300832,"retry_count":5,"retried_at":1476246151.9909208}
2016-10-12T04:22:31.991Z 73605 TID-y7u04 WARN: TypeError: exception class/object expected
2016-10-12T04:22:31.991Z 73605 TID-y7u04 WARN: /home/ubuntu/ruby_projects/VideoShrimp/app/workers/thumbnail_cutter.rb:13:in raise' /home/ubuntu/ruby_projects/VideoShrimp/app/workers/thumbnail_cutter.rb:13:inperform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:155:in execute_job' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:inblock (3 levels) in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in block in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/sidetiq-7bec4084165f/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:8:incall'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in block in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:incall'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in block in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:incall'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in block in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:inblock in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in with_context' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:incall'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in block in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:incall'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in invoke' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:inblock (2 levels) in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:171:in stats' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:130:inblock in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:in call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:inblock in module:Sidekiq'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:122:in call' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:122:inprocess'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:81:in process_one' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:69:inrun'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in watchdog' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:inblock in safe_thread'
2016-10-12T04:23:00.332Z 73605 TID-l83gw INFO: [Sidetiq] Enqueue: VideoPublisher (at: 1476246240.0) (last: 1476246180.0)
2016-10-12T04:23:03.189Z 73605 TID-nzbss VideoPublisher JID-3868cff6ecf16611b931cab4 INFO: start
2016-10-12T04:23:03.202Z 73605 TID-nzbss VideoPublisher JID-3868cff6ecf16611b931cab4 INFO: done: 0.013 sec
2016-10-12T04:24:00.354Z 73605 TID-ou3i0 INFO: [Sidetiq] Enqueue: VideoPublisher (at: 1476246300.0) (last: 1476246240.0)
2016-10-12T04:24:01.846Z 73605 TID-vgq5w VideoPublisher JID-267f4344c307579fa8ba2a52 INFO: start
2016-10-12T04:24:01.848Z 73605 TID-vgq5w VideoPublisher JID-267f4344c307579fa8ba2a52 INFO: done: 0.002 sec
```

Comment: This blog is a little old and hasn't been updated. I'll have the author review and comment.

Answer (score 2):

`sidekiq 4.2.2 VideoShrimp [0 of 25 busy]: No such file or directory - ffmpeg` - You don't have `ffmpeg` installed on your system or executable is not in your `PATH`.

Installing ffmpeg should help, you can do that on ubuntu this way: `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` (I'm assuming you're on ubuntu because of `/home/ubuntu`).

The `[64544] 11 Oct 07:36:14.427 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use` indicates that socket is already in use so you probably have redis server already running.